# Refreshing Admin page when saving sql connection string

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have created the ability to update the sql connection string within the web.config file. However, for some reason I can't get it to update in real time without refreshing the page. Once I refresh my page it shows the changed value. It saves in the web.config file when I click save but returns to the old value.

Here is my AdminModel:

```
   public void SAVEsqlConnection(string sqlConnection)
    {
        if (sqlConnection != System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection1"].ToString())
        {
            Configuration sqlConnection1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)sqlConnection1.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            section.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection1"].ConnectionString = sqlConnection;
            sqlConnection1.Save();
        }
    }
```

Here is my AdminController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Admin(string txt_file_dest, string report_dest, string sql_Connection)
    {
        AdminModel Values = new AdminModel();

        if (sql_Connection != null)
        {
            Values.SAVEsqlConnection(sql_Connection);       
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Here is my Admin.cshtml file:

```
    <input type="text" name="sql_Connection" value= "@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection1"]">
    :SQL Connection String<br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save Changes" />
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have a deadline to make.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, how do you expect this to work? Of course you have to refresh the page, so ASP.net re-generates the content after reading in the new connections string.

Comment: Correct. But I need for it to refresh when I click save so that the user does not have to refresh the page. That way it shows the string they changed it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page using this bit of JavaScript (1.2) after the query has been done:

```
 <script>
 window.location.reload(true); 
 </script>
```

Althought, AJAX would be a better solution because it would make the page autoload new content.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Admin(string txt_file_dest, string report_dest, string sql_Connection)
    {
        AdminModel Values = new AdminModel();

        if (sql_Connection != null)
        {
            Values.SAVEsqlConnection(sql_Connection);       
        }

         return RedirectToAction("actionname");//call same page action again
    }
```